# Is there anything in Hinduism to refute the idea that plant species are controlled by a single soul?

Tags: scripture, atma, science, consciousness, plants

I feel like the most sensible answer to how plant souls work when plants can have cuttings is to say plants are single souled and the entire species is controlled by one soul. This makes sense with Hindu stories like the curse on the Ketaki flower somehow applying to all of them. Is there any scripture that contradicts this idea?

In case you don't see the conundrum, how does the cutting survive when the origin plant dies? The new soul also can't rely on a small vessel otherwise the soul wouldn't be able to exert enough control to control the body, especially for organisms without brains, like plants.

Comment: why does the existence of cuttings cause confusion ? a man's seed is after all, part of his own body, yet you consider that a different soul when it enters a womb, right ? every cell, every water droplet in our body could host a million atmas. but only 1 is karma-adheena i.e. enjoys/suffers that body.

Comment: @mar How does the cutting survive when the origin plant dies?

Comment: @mar Also, the soul can't be tied to such a small area, otherwise, it would barely have any control. Especially for organisms without brains.

Comment: who said it is tied to a small area ? the karma-adhina atma has jnana over entire body. all other atmas are in dormant state, but physically tied to that body. once the cutting out is done, some atma that was in that part gets new 'life' and its karma-cycle kicks off.

Comment: @mar Well if the original can control its body from multiple locations, why would a new soul need to take control when there is a cutting? It could just remain in control.

Comment: who said it can control its body from 'multiple' locations ? it can control it's body for the entire length/breadth of body. Same with human reproduction. A man can control what he does with his private parts, but once the seed goes out, the atma in that seed gets new body based on karma.

Comment: @mar Your body is in multiple locations. If the soul's control was fixed in a small location, then it wouldn't be able to exert enough control to control its body.

Comment: it's still one contiguous body. if your arm is cut off and i pinch it, you won't feel pain. the nervous systems attached to spine/brain are necessary to 'feel'. Devas, Rishis etc. can feel their body/bodies from multiple disparate locations.

Comment: @mar That just causes a contradiction with organisms without brains (like plants). Also, even the brain on its own is too big to be controlled from one location.

Comment: i gave the brain only as an analogy. there are unicellular organisms without brains that respond to stimuli anywhere on their body. the existence of a brain is not necessary. what is necessary is the existence of a contiguous body.

Comment: This is related to a previously asked question. All living things have their own individual jiva. All plants have their individual jivas ans well as all the cells in those plants have their own individual jivas. All living cells have their own individual jivas. Besides your own jiva which is 'you', all the cells in your body have their own individual jivas. Iswara is the summation of all jivas.